# How to give name of MainWindow.xib file in plist file at run time?

Tags: iphone

I want to give the name of MainWindow.xib file in plist file through code, How I can achieve this, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MainWindow.xib cannot be updated in the pList. sins the plist is loaded and its copied inside the application bundle, and you will have no write access to it.